# How can I fetch data from an outside relational database using an Ajax call from within a Wix website?

Tags: velo

How can I fetch data from an outside relational database using an Ajax call from within a Wix website?

Make an Ajax call from within Wix to a relational database that is hosted on an AWS EC2 server.

The key here is to do this from within a Wix.com website.

Any assistance in accomplishing this goal is greatly appreciated.